# Why is my writefile() not compiling?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, command-line-arguments, printstream

The `writefile()` method should write out to the given output file all the integers in the given array, one per line. For this part, the merge method should return a new array big enough to hold the content of the first two arrays (a and b), and then the first two copied into that array, without regard for order.

This is what is put in the command line when running the program:

> java Merge1 sorted1.txt sorted2.txt sortedout.txt

This is what is in sorted1.txt.

> 12
>   51
>   80
>   138
>   212
>   237
>   306
>   316
>   317
>   337
>   356
>   413
>   422
>   511
>   534
>   577
>   621
>   708
>   717
>   738
>   738
>   846
>   850
>   900

This is what is sorted2.txt:

> 33
>   41
>   77
>   101
>   157
>   164
>   192
>   235
>   412
>   415
>   484
>   499
>   500
>   533
>   565
>   630
>   667
>   786
>   846
>   851
>   911
>   949
>   968
>   986

How would I do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Merge1
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    File sorted1 = new File (args[0]);
    File sorted2 = new File (args[1]);
    File sortedout = new File (args[2]);
    try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(sorted1);
    readfile(input);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");   
    }
    try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(sorted2);
    readfile(input);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");   
    }
    try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(sortedout);
    readfile(input);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");   
    }




} // end main

static int[] readfile(Scanner input)
{

    String num = "";
    while(input.hasNextInt())
    {
        num += input.nextInt() + " ";
    }
    String[] array = num.split(" ");
    int[] list = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        list[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
    return list;

} // end readfile

static void writefile(PrintStream output, int[] a)
{   
    output.println(merge(int[] a, int[]b)); 

} // end writefile 

static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b)
{
        int[] answer = new int[a.length + b.length];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (i < a.length && j < b.length)
        {
            if (a[i] < b[j])
            {       
                    answer[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
                }

            else  
            {      
                    answer[k] = b[j]; 
            k++;
            j++;
            }              
        }

        while (i < a.length)  
        {
            answer[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }

    while (j < b.length)
    {    
            answer[k] = b[j];
        k++;
        j++;
        }   

    return answer;

} // end merge  


} // end Merge1
```

Comment: Which part won't compile? With what message?

Comment: it does not like the line output.prinln(merge(int[] a, int [] b);

Comment: because you create arrays witn **new** keyword, and if you want to pass an array that already exists, you can use just its name a or b.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the `System.arraycopy` method to copy one array into the other, but you could also use a dynamic array, like an `ArrayList`. [System.arraycopy description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

As for the write method, all what is needed is the `PrintStream` you pass, opened with a `FileOutputStream` and a simple `println` for each values. For the sorting there are plenty of sorting algorithms, some collections already have a sort method implemented.

Comment: How do I open the FileOutputStream and print the array?

Comment: @anderkat Wherever you create your PrintStream (probably in your `main`), you do `PrintStream stream = new PrintStream (new FileOutputStream ("filename.txt"))` then pass it to your write method. But you should try to google a bit, the link I provided for `System.arraycopy` was extremely easy to find. There are so many official docs and examples on google and stackoverflow, you can't miss it.

Comment: @anderkat97 Unfortunately I can't reply to your question's comment due to my reputation, but concerning the compiler complaining on your write method because of your merge method, println accepts a single value, not an array, you need to store your array in a local temporary variable and loop through every values and print them individually.